Sorting an array of {k:string , v: int} objects Ascending and Alphaberical at the same time. JavaScript
I recently had a training task:
given the array of {"color":string,"size":int} Objects, print them sorted by size. If multiple objects share same size, they,among themselves, should be sorted by color alphabetically.
I have written this:
//example:
let x = [{"color":"green" ,"size":42},{"color":"blue" ,"size":42},{"color":"red" ,"size":42},{"color":"blue" ,"size":41}];

//1st - sorting by size:
x=x.sort((a,b)=>a.size-b.size)

//2nd - find unique sizes.
const uniqueSizes = [...new Set(x.map(item => item.size))]; 

//3rd - group the initial array into individual arrays of same size
let grouped=[]
for (const size of uniqueSizes){
  let found=x.filter((f)=>f.size===size);
  grouped.push(found)
}
console.log(grouped)

//last - sort individual groups and print them.
for (const g of grouped){
  console.log(
    g.sort((a,b)=>a.color.localeCompare(b.color)).map(z=>`${z.size} ${z.color}`).join(`\n`)
  )
}

Here is the result:
41 blue
42 blue
42 green
42 red

Question:
Is there an easier/more elegant way to do this? I think , solution is cumbersome and creates a lot of unnecessary variables + i think that step by step approach is also time consuming;

Well, there's the array .sort() method, have you looked into that? It's going to be the most efficient way to do it, especially if the list is long.

@Pointy I have read that article exactly, though copy-pasted to another site. Most of the examples provided are quite basic there. this is why my array.sort function is so basic. And this question is basically a way to open up the complexity of the topic for me. Luckly the answer accepted is what I needed exactly :)

Wouldn't this do the trick?
let x = [
  { color: 'green', size: 42 },
  { color: 'blue', size: 42 },
  { color: 'red', size: 42 },
  { color: 'blue', size: 41 },
];

x.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.size === b.size) {
    return a.color.localeCompare(b.color);
  }

  return a.size - b.size;
});

You could also use toSorted instead if you don't want to mutate x, and your target supports it.
let x = [
  { color: 'green', size: 42 },
  { color: 'blue', size: 42 },
  { color: 'red', size: 42 },
  { color: 'blue', size: 41 },
];

x.toSorted((a, b) => {
  if (a.size === b.size) {
    return a.color.localeCompare(b.color);
  }

  return a.size - b.size;
});

This is the output from logging the code above:
[
  { "color": "blue", "size": 41 },
  { "color": "blue", "size": 42 },
  { "color": "green", "size": 42 },
  { "color": "red", "size": 42 }
]


Hey! Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. I guess as a beginner I feared that sorting with many returns within the arrow function is going to be quite challenging. most of the examples of the array.sort functions are quite basic. this definitely opens up the topic for me
